# how to properly concatenate bidi strings in r?

Tags: r, shiny, string-concatenation, bidi, urdu

I want to add markup to (Urdu language) text that is written right to left. I am trying to use gsub for the purpose but everything I have tried so far does not produce the desired output

```
text <- "یہ جملہ ایک مثال کے لیے استعمال کیا جا رہا ہے"
pattern <- "کیا جا"
replaceWith <- paste0("<somemark>", pattern, "</somemark>")
gsub(pattern, replaceWith, text)
```

gsub returns the following

```
یہ جملہ ایک مثال کے لیے استعمال <somemark>کیا جا</somemark> رہا ہے
```

desired output .

[image]

How can I acheive the desired output?

**Note:** I could not even properly typeset the desired output in my post, I had to rely on an image instead.

**Update:** Although `mysub` function below correctly concatenates the strings(in console), I continue to face the problem of incorrect order of text in shiny app.

```
mysub <- function(text, pattern){
beforePattern <- substr(text, 1, regexpr(pattern, text)[1]-1)
afterPattern <- substr(text, regexpr(pattern,text)[1] + nchar(pattern), nchar(text))
result <- paste(afterPattern, replaceWith, beforePattern)
result
}
```

Comment: Hm, the output is basically reversed? Is this maybe because of the font? Is it written from right to left? (Sorry, I am european...)

Comment: No, to the best of my knowledge it's not a font issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a try . I did take the liberty of hard coding the args instead of reading from session, though.

```
Server: 

output$mysub <- function(){ # (text=NULL, pattern=NULL)

text <- "یہ جملہ ایک مثال کے لیے استعمال کیا جا رہا ہے"
pattern <- "کیا جا"

Encoding(text) <- "UTF-8"
Encoding(pattern) <- "UTF-8"

print(text)

beforePattern <- substr(text, 1, regexpr(pattern, text)[1]-1)
afterPattern <- substr(text, regexpr(pattern,text)[1] + nchar(pattern), nchar(text))

replaceWith <- paste0("<somemark>", pattern, "</somemark>")
result <- paste(afterPattern, replaceWith, beforePattern)

# result <- paste( beforePattern, replaceWith, afterPattern)
# Encoding(result) <- "UTF-8"
print(length(result))
print(result)

return(result)
}


# ui.R: 

h2( textOutput("mysub") )
```

The output I got on shiny webpage was :
[image: bidi text output]

Answer (score 3):

There is actually no problem with `gsub`:

```
text <- dput("یہ جملہ ایک مثال کے لیے استعمال کیا جا رہا ہے")
"<U+06CC><U+06C1> <U+062C><U+0645><U+0644><U+06C1> <U+0627><U+06CC><U+06A9>
<U+0645><U+062B><U+0627><U+0644> <U+06A9><U+06D2> <U+0644><U+06CC><U+06D2> 
<U+0627><U+0633><U+062A><U+0639><U+0645><U+0627><U+0644> <U+06A9><U+06CC>
<U+0627> <U+062C><U+0627> <U+0631><U+06C1><U+0627> <U+06C1><U+06D2>"

pattern <- dput("کیا جا")
"<U+06A9><U+06CC><U+0627> <U+062C><U+0627>"

replaceWith <- dput(paste0("<somemark>", pattern, "</somemark>"))
"<somemark><U+06A9><U+06CC><U+0627> <U+062C><U+0627></somemark>"

dput(gsub(pattern, replaceWith, text))
"<U+06CC><U+06C1> <U+062C><U+0645><U+0644><U+06C1> <U+0627><U+06CC><U+06A9> 
<U+0645><U+062B><U+0627><U+0644> <U+06A9><U+06D2> <U+0644><U+06CC><U+06D2> 
<U+0627><U+0633><U+062A><U+0639><U+0645><U+0627><U+0644> <somemark><U+06A9>
<U+06CC><U+0627> <U+062C><U+0627></somemark> <U+0631><U+06C1><U+0627> 
<U+06C1><U+06D2>"
```

The rendering of the result ( a string containing both right to left and left to right characters) is also quite logical to me:

1. The beginning of the string contains right to left characters so is rendered from right to left

`یہ جملہ ایک مثال کے لیے استعمال`

2. then the string continues with left to right characters. It is rendered left to right and added at the end (the left of what was previously rendered),

`یہ جملہ ایک مثال کے لیے استعمال <somemark>`

3. then the string continues with right to left characters. It is rendered right to left and added at the end,

`یہ جملہ ایک مثال کے لیے استعمال <somemark>کیا جا`

4. then the string continues with left to right characters. It is rendered left to right and added at the end,

`یہ جملہ ایک مثال کے لیے استعمال <somemark>کیا جا</somemark>`

5. and finally the string ends with right to left characters. It is rendered right to left and added at the end.

`یہ جملہ ایک مثال کے لیے استعمال <somemark>کیا جا</somemark> رہا ہے`

Your idea of what should be rendered doesn't seem to me more logical, but I must admit I don't have experience with right to left text rendering.

Anyway, if the formatting has to be interpreted by the renderer like the `<b>...</b>` tags in HTML, then it works perfectly (in markdown/html):

`یہ جملہ ایک مثال کے لیے استعمال <b>کیا جا</b> رہا ہے`

renders as

یہ جملہ ایک مثال کے لیے استعمال **کیا جا** رہا ہے

I have not managed to print nothing in shiny but question marks:

`???? ???????? ?????? ???????? ???? ?????? ?????????????? <somemark>?????? ????</somemark> ?????? ????`

Comment: As you mentioned the rendering works perfectly in markdown+html, rendering in shiny is problematic. Will it be possible to append unicode control characters for instructing right-to-left and left-to-right rendering of string?

Comment: @ImranAli, Yes, unicode control characters are useful here: `gsub(pattern, replaceWith, paste0("\u202b", text, "\u202c"))` seems to work. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45109292/1851712) for more details.