# Concatenate left-to-right (LTR) and right-to-left (RTL) text

Tags: r, unicode, arabic, bidi, arabic-support

It seems that combining left-to-right (LTR) and right-to-left (RTL) text using `paste` can produce unexpected results for the resulting order:

```
(x = paste(c('green', 'أحمر', 'أزرق'), collapse=' ')) # arabic for blue and red
#> [1] "green أحمر أزرق"
paste(x, 'yellow')
#> [1] "green أحمر أزرق yellow"
paste(x, 123)
#> [1] "green أحمر أزرق 123"
```

Is there any known solution to this - i.e. a way to ensure concatenation in the same sequence as the arguments are given?  Perhaps the answer is *don't concatenate different alphabets*!

Comment: Even typing `x = paste(c('green',<foreign text>, 123, collapse=' '))` in a text editor gives me a similar issue. I can't even format it correctly here...

Comment: I'm unsure, but this is due to numbers being always encoded as LTR (left-to-right), therefore it's `123`. But in case of Arabic it's added on the left of the Arabic text - therefore later in the Arabic text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the Unicode control characters ['left-to-right embedding'](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Explicit_Directional_Embeddings), `u202A` ("Treat the following text as embedded left-to-right"):

```
paste(x, "\u202A", 123)
# [1] "green أحمر أزرق ‭ 123"
```

---

See also [Terminating Explicit Directional Embeddings and Overrides](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Terminating_Explicit_Directional_Embeddings_and_Overrides), (`u202C`), a thorough description on [UNICODE BIDIRECTIONAL ALGORITHM](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/), and [here](https://xkcd.com/1137/).

Comment: Well butter my parsnips. [U+1F4AA]